# Android multi state toggleButton

Tags: android, kotlin, toggle

I using this library to make multi state toggleButton
https://github.com/jlhonora/multistatetogglebutton

Everything works fine now.

My issue is how can make the toggle button clicked based on a value given?

Example there are three values in toggle, A,B,and C, which is in Activity B.

I'm passing value `A` from **Activity One** to **Activity Two**. When it comes to **Activity Two**, the toggle which has value A should be clicked.

Comment: Can you click on the button programmatically with this library?

Comment: @TamirAbutbul Don't know how. I only know how to manual click

Comment: @TamirAbutbul or do you have any idea on how to create multi state toggle button ?

Comment: and by  "I only know how to manual click" do you mean the library or generally

Comment: @TamirAbutbul the library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you set the chosen button by it's position. You could retrieve all the texts of the buttons, find the index of the text that matches your text, and then set the chosen button with that index.

Pseudo Code:

```
val dataFromActivityOne = intent.getString("blah")
multiStateToggle.setValue(multiStateToggle.texts.indexOf(dataFromActivityOne))
```

Comment: there are no setValue in the library

Comment: It's here: https://github.com/jlhonora/multistatetogglebutton/blob/37275832634a31c7917cb44aa480f3c303031315/multistatetogglebutton/src/org/honorato/multistatetogglebutton/MultiStateToggleButton.java#L330